# opacityアニメーションが背景にかからない問題

Tags: javascript, html, css

LPを作っておりそこでopacityで透明度操作することが必要だったのですが、背景にopacity加工がかからず透明にならない状態です
他の加工もうまくかからないのですが、この件どなたか解決策をご存知でしょうか？もしCSSだけで解決不可の問題でしたらJavascriptを使っていただいてもかまいませんので、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

```css
body {
  animation: blackout 6s infinite;
  height:100vh;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

@keyframes blackout {
  0% {
background:red;
opacity:1;
  }
  50% {
    background:blue;
opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    background: red;
opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: HTML は実際のコードも div タグのみなのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございました。ほかにもタグはあるのですが実際のコードを改変していても問題が起こったので最後に試していた状態をのせた次第です

Answer (score 3, accepted):

この回答は、通常不透明な白色とされているキャンバスが、`opacity` プロパティの変化の過程で透けて表示されない、という問題に対する回答です。もし質問への回答になっていない場合は無視してください。

---

HTML 文書において、`body` 要素に設定された `background` プロパティの計算値は、ルート要素である `html` 要素へ伝播され、本来の `body` 要素の `background` プロパティは初期値として扱われます<sup>[[1]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#body-background)</sup>。これは、`body` 要素に指定した背景関連のプロパティは `html` 要素へ設定されたかのように振る舞う、ということを意味しています。

このことから、 `body` 要素に設定した `background: red` および `background: blue` の 2 つのスタイルは、`html` 要素へ設定されたかのように振る舞うと理解できます。仕様上、ルート要素である `html` 要素の背景はキャンバスの背景となります<sup>[[2]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#root-background)</sup>。つまり、キャンバスの不透明な白色の背景は、`body` 要素から伝播された `background` プロパティによって上書きされるということです。これがキャンバスが `opacity` プロパティの変化の過程で透けて表示されない原因です。

この問題の解決策は、`html` 要素に明示的に背景を指定することです。今回は問題が生じませんが、`body` 要素で明示的に高さを設定する必要がある点に注意してください。

> ##### § 2.11.2. The Canvas Background and the HTML `<body>` Element<sup>[[1]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#body-background)</sup>
>
> For documents whose root element is an HTML HTML element or an XHTML
> html element [HTML]: if the computed value of background-image on the
> root element is none and its background-color is transparent, user
> agents must instead propagate the computed values of the background
> properties from that element’s first HTML BODY or XHTML body child
> element. The used values of that BODY element’s background properties
> are their initial values, and the propagated values are treated as if
> they were specified on the root element. It is recommended that
> authors of HTML documents specify the canvas background for the BODY
> element rather than the HTML element.

> ##### § 2.11.1. The Canvas Background and the Root Element<sup>[[2]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#root-background)</sup>
>
> The background of the root element becomes the canvas background and
> its background painting area extends to cover the entire canvas.
> However, any images are sized and positioned relative to the root
> element as if they were painted for that element alone. (In other
> words, the background positioning area is determined as for the root
> element.) The root element does not paint this background again, i.e.,
> the used value of its background is transparent.

```css
html {
  background-color: white;  /* 追加 */
}

body {
  animation: blackout 6s infinite;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@keyframes blackout {
  0% {
    background: red;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    background: blue;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    background: red;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 背景にopacity加工がかからず透明にならない

「透明になる」とはどのような状態を期待されているのでしょうか？ 質問コードは`body`要素を透明に操作していますが、透明になった結果何が見えることを期待していますか？ Webブラウザーの裏側にいるデスクトップ背景が表示されることを期待されているのでしょうか？ 当然ながらそのようなことはできません。

質問のコードをそのままに、操作対象を`div`要素とし、`body`要素の背景色を変えると`opacity`は正しく機能していることが確認できます。

```css
body {
  background: yellow;
}

div {
  animation: blackout 6s infinite;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@keyframes blackout {
  0% {
    background: red;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    background: blue;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    background: red;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```